# Using VBA to find a string in a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and using it perform fucntions in excel. I am attempting to search through the A column for a string "Parts Subtotal". Once this string is found within the column, I then want to select the cell that is 13 cells to the right. I know you have to use a combination of the find and offset functions but I nothing I try seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want. Now show us what you have tried in your question, and explain the problem you ran into. Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free coding site where you post an idea and someone writes the code for you.

Comment: `Find` and `Offset` is certainly one approach. Can you [edit] your question with what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Index As Integer = 1

Do Until Range(Index).Value = "Parts Subtotal"
        Index +=1
Loop
Range("N" & Index).Activate
```